Tesseract OCR - How to get more accurate results
How can I get more accurate results for codes that aren't "plain English"? I have tried all of the PSM options and 6 seems to work the best, but the accuracy rate is only about 10%. 
I have tried the following:
$output = (new TesseractOCR($localPath))->psm(6)->run();
$output = (new TesseractOCR($localPath))->setLanguage('eng')->psm(6)->run();
The text in the image is not being converted accurately with TesseractOCR. For instance, as you can see in the attached image, F10.20 becomes I0.20, F14.20 becomes F1a20, F41.1 becomes Fatal, Z71.3 becomes za, etc. These are medical codes for patients and must be converted accurately.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The text in the image is not being converted accurately with TesseractOCR. For instance, as you can see in the attached image, F10.20 becomes I0.20, F14.20 becomes F1a20, F41.1 becomes Fatal, Z71.3 becomes za, etc. These are medical codes for patients and must be converted accurately.
